# Consumer does not read messages from the Kafka topic (Akka Stream Kafka)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, java-8, akka-stream, kafka-transactions-api

We use Akka Stream Kafka for producing and consuming messages and Strimzi Kafka cluster.
Here are the versions if matters:

```
com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream-kafka_2.13:2.0.7
  com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.13:2.6.14
  org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.4.1 (*)
  org.scala-lang.modules:scala-collection-compat_2.13:2.1.6
  org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.5
```

After a refactoring message consumer stopped working.
We do have messages in the topic, but consumer just waits endlessly.

Here is the log fragment:

```
[2021-04-14 21:20:43,869] [INFO] [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-8] - Kafka version: 2.4.1
[2021-04-14 21:20:43,869] [INFO] [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-8] - Kafka commitId: c57222ae8cd7866b
[2021-04-14 21:20:43,869] [INFO] [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-8] - Kafka startTimeMs: 1618424443866
[2021-04-14 21:20:43,879] [INFO] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-8] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Subscribed to topic(s): xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic
[2021-04-14 21:20:45,907] [INFO] [org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-19] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Cluster ID: L9OdIPABTGa7V9OPdViAaw
[2021-04-14 21:20:45,973] [INFO] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-21] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Discovered group coordinator kafka-staging-abc-cluster-kafka-0-kafka-abc.xyzabccluster-host:443 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
[2021-04-14 21:20:46,245] [INFO] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-21] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] (Re-)joining group
[2021-04-14 21:20:47,554] [INFO] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-9] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] (Re-)joining group
[2021-04-14 21:20:50,780] [INFO] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-22] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Finished assignment for group at generation 5: {consumer-xyz-abc-import-1-995fd3d7-24b5-480d-90bc-b0967f0898f0=Assignment(partitions=[xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1])}
[2021-04-14 21:20:51,114] [INFO] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-16] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Successfully joined group with generation 5
[2021-04-14 21:20:51,125] [INFO] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-16] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Adding newly assigned partitions: xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1
[2021-04-14 21:20:51,334] [INFO] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-18] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Setting offset for partition xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=38, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=kafka-staging-abc-cluster-kafka-0-kafka-abc.xyzabccluster-host:443 (id: 0 rack: null), epoch=0}}
[2021-04-14 21:20:51,336] [INFO] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-18] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Setting offset for partition xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=51, offsetEpoch=Optional[0], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=kafka-staging-abc-cluster-kafka-1-kafka-abc.xyzabccluster-host:443 (id: 1 rack: null), epoch=0}}
```

Some more points:

1. Schema registry properly configured and good (otherwise producer would not work).
2. Topic (and group coordinator) is good, I can consume messages via plain consumer like that:

```
KafkaConsumer<String, MyMsg> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, MyMsg>(props);
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(inputTopic), rebalanceListener);
ConsumerRecords<String, MyMsg> records = consumer.poll(Duration.of(60L, ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
```

3. I use "earliest" reset config property, so it should see unconsumed messages.
4. This is what I have in the topic when I run - in partition 1 I have messages at offset 51 and 52, and consumer coordinator set to offset 51 in log, so the message is there (in fact, it must read 2 messages I produced for this testing)

[image: topic state]

This is the place where the code stuck -- I use blocking call to get 2 messages (and cannot get even 1)

```
final Source<ProducerMessage.Results<String, Object, ConsumerMessage.PartitionOffset>, NotUsed> stream = ...
stream.take(SUBMISSION_SIZE).runWith(Sink.ignore(), mat).toCompletableFuture().get();
```

Not really sure how to debug it. 8-(

**[UPD 1]**

Can it relate somehow to transactions? Bacause plain Akka Stream Consumer can see the messages and consume:

```
    @Test
    @Order(3)
    void exploreTopic() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Consumer.DrainingControl<java.util.List<ConsumerRecord<String, Object>>> controlCompletionStagePair =
            Consumer.plainSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(inputTopic))
                .take(SUBMISSION_SIZE)
                .map(x -> {
                    System.out.println(x);
                    return x;
                })
                .toMat(Sink.seq(), Consumer::createDrainingControl)
                .run(mat);
        controlCompletionStagePair.streamCompletion().toCompletableFuture().get();
        System.out.println("xxx");
    }
```

**[UPD 2]**

I turned on DEBUG level of logging and see my partitions are placed on pause:

```
[2021-04-14 23:46:05,122] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher] [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | xyz-abc-import] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Fetch READ_COMMITTED at offset 40 for partition xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0 returned fetch data (error=NONE, highWaterMark=40, lastStableOffset = 40, logStartOffset = 40, preferredReadReplica = absent, abortedTransactions = [], recordsSizeInBytes=0)
[2021-04-14 23:46:05,725] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-6] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Added READ_COMMITTED fetch request for partition xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0 at position FetchPosition{offset=40, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=kafka-staging-abc-cluster-kafka-0-kafka-abc.xyzabccluster-host:443 (id: 0 rack: null), epoch=0}} to node kafka-staging-abc-cluster-kafka-0-kafka-abc.xyzabccluster-host:443 (id: 0 rack: null)
[2021-04-14 23:46:05,725] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-6] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Added READ_COMMITTED fetch request for partition xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1 at position FetchPosition{offset=61, offsetEpoch=Optional[0], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=kafka-staging-abc-cluster-kafka-1-kafka-abc.xyzabccluster-host:443 (id: 1 rack: null), epoch=0}} to node kafka-staging-abc-cluster-kafka-1-kafka-abc.xyzabccluster-host:443 (id: 1 rack: null)
[2021-04-14 23:46:05,725] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-6] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Built incremental fetch (sessionId=339828876, epoch=1) for node 0. Added 0 partition(s), altered 0 partition(s), removed 0 partition(s) out of 1 partition(s)
[2021-04-14 23:46:05,725] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-6] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Built incremental fetch (sessionId=23429972, epoch=1) for node 1. Added 0 partition(s), altered 1 partition(s), removed 0 partition(s) out of 1 partition(s)
[2021-04-14 23:46:05,725] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-6] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Sending READ_COMMITTED IncrementalFetchRequest(toSend=(), toForget=(), implied=(xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0)) to broker kafka-staging-abc-cluster-kafka-0-kafka-abc.xyzabccluster-host:443 (id: 0 rack: null)
[2021-04-14 23:46:05,726] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-6] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Sending READ_COMMITTED IncrementalFetchRequest(toSend=(xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1), toForget=(), implied=()) to broker kafka-staging-abc-cluster-kafka-1-kafka-abc.xyzabccluster-host:443 (id: 1 rack: null)
[2021-04-14 23:46:05,796] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-7] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Pausing partitions [xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1]
[2021-04-14 23:46:05,866] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-10] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Pausing partitions [xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1]
[2021-04-14 23:46:05,935] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-11] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Pausing partitions [xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1]
[2021-04-14 23:46:06,009] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-13] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Pausing partitions [xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1]
[2021-04-14 23:46:06,075] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-15] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Pausing partitions [xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1]
[2021-04-14 23:46:06,149] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-18] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Pausing partitions [xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1]
[2021-04-14 23:46:06,215] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-20] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Pausing partitions [xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1]
[2021-04-14 23:46:06,288] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-21] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Pausing partitions [xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1]
[2021-04-14 23:46:06,355] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-8] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Pausing partitions [xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1]
[2021-04-14 23:46:06,355] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator] [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | xyz-abc-import] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator kafka-staging-abc-cluster-kafka-0-kafka-abc.xyzabccluster-host:443 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
[2021-04-14 23:46:06,427] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-9] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Pausing partitions [xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1]
[2021-04-14 23:46:06,459] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler] [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | xyz-abc-import] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Node 1 sent an incremental fetch response for session 23429972 with 0 response partition(s), 1 implied partition(s)
[2021-04-14 23:46:06,459] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler] [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | xyz-abc-import] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Node 0 sent an incremental fetch response for session 339828876 with 0 response partition(s), 1 implied partition(s)
[2021-04-14 23:46:06,500] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-12] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Pausing partitions [xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1]
[2021-04-14 23:46:06,557] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-14] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Pausing partitions [xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1]
[2021-04-14 23:46:06,559] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-14] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Received successful Heartbeat response
[2021-04-14 23:46:06,625] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-16] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Pausing partitions [xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1]
[2021-04-14 23:46:06,697] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-17] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Pausing partitions [xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1]
[2021-04-14 23:46:06,765] [DEBUG] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] [SchemaRegistrySerializationTest-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-19] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-abc-import-1, groupId=xyz-abc-import] Pausing partitions [xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-0, xyz-abc-import-dev-abc-input-topic-1]
```

**[UPD 3]**
Does it have to do with auto created topics?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell how it impacts, but consumer started working properly once I added this property to consumer:

```
props.put(AvroDatumProvider.REGISTRY_USE_SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG_PARAM, String.valueOf(Boolean.TRUE));
```

Now sure what was the real cause, and why there was no error thrown, but adding property above helped, at least in my case.